# How do I remove this blank space to the left of this header?

Tags: html, css

I've started recently learning css and html by myself, and I wanted to make a header/banner at the top of the page with some menus etc., but I realized that there is this ["gap"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysq15.png) to the left of the header.

This is my css for this header.

```
.header {
    background: #555;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

this is the html

```
    <div class="header">
        <!-- code -->
    </div>
```

Comment: please post your HTML and CSS

Comment: Please provide your html code as well

Comment: i added the html

Comment: Where is your image?

Comment: oh wait i thought i added it

Comment: ok its added now

Comment: Use `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try again with this code.
You have to set `left: 0;`

```css
.header {
    background: #555;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
        <h3 class="header-name">Hype RP</h3>
    </div>
```